# B2C - Tab Index incorrect for Sign In

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Using User Flow or Custom Policy and creating a signup/sign in flow the TAB indexes are off for sign in screen. We use custom policies but this is an issue around the layout being used, I believe.

Steps:

1. Create a Sign Up/Sign In User Flow following the steps at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow
2. Make sure you followed the steps in pre-requisites for setting up an app registration
3. Run the User Flow to test it out
4. Place your cursor in the username/email field and enter an email
5. Press TAB key on keyboard
6. Expectation would be to go to the password field next, but it does not

Reference these [page templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#select-a-page-template), for example Ocean Blue or Slate Gray.

See also [page layout version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout), we are using the ones in the article.

For example with `api.signuporsignin`, we are using `2.1.7` version for `unified.html`

```xml
<ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin"> 
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:2.1.7</DataUri> 
</ContentDefinition>
```

Comment: I do see reference to this same issue [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/issues/101). Other suggestions?

Comment: I have tried to replicate the scenario and able to use TAB to go into the sign in page using user flow or custom policy. Did you try in another browser. Could you please share the screenshot of issue for better understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is configure passwordlinklocation in technical profile of custom policy.

```
<Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">AfterInput</Item>
```

you may have to change css little bit.

Comment: Great workaround to fix the issue w/o JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If tab index is not proper, then try some javascript

```
        document.getElementById("email").tabIndex = 1;
        document.getElementById("password").tabIndex = 2;
        document.getElementById("next").tabIndex = 4;
        document.getElementById("forgotPassword").tabIndex = 3;
        if(document.getElementById("createAccount"))
            document.getElementById("createAccount").tabIndex = 5;
        document.getElementById("email").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details to the issue, in response to @shwetam.

The issue is seen in the latest version of Chrome (Version 112.0.5615.49 (Official Build) (x86_64).

I do NOT experience the issue in Firefox or Safari. (I am using a Mac).

Comment: This answer should have been a comment

Comment: I agree with you 100%, just that since I dont have the necessary "reputation", Stack overflow would not let me comment. I felt getting the info out there was more important than just leaving it. If you are able to add a comment, I will delete my answer (since its not really answer).